# Poner elementos de html una debajo de otro

Tags: html5, css

Hola mi estructura html sería:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #62ADD6;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
}

#pie {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2f43c1;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#section {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  color: blue;
  /*height: calc(100% - 120px);*/
  height: 750px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

¿Cómo podría hacer que el footer estuviera debajo del section y aunque este se hiciera más grande que el tamaño de la pantalla el footer se bajara con el final del section?

Comment: Hola Bsg, bienvenid@. Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? Por que no te ha funcionado? errores/problemas? Un saludo.

Comment: el footer tiene esto: #pie{
 background-color:#2f43c1;
 bottom: 0;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
  } /n pero al meter cosas de gran tamaño  en el section se mete por debajo y el footer se queda en el mismo lugar.

Comment: Hola bsg, pon el código completo... y dinos si estás aplicando alguna hoja de estilos ya definida por ti o genérica.

Comment: El css es definido por mi. Ya está puesto el css.

Comment: Si no se añade nada entre las etiquetas da igual que se pueda ejecutar... No se ve el resultado.

Answer (score 3):

No se muy bien lo que preguntas. Con un display block estaría un bloque debajo del anterior segun su disposición en el HTML, p.e.:

```css
     nav,
     footer,
     section { 
      display: block;
      height: 100px;
     }
     nav {
      background: grey
     }
     footer {
      background: pink
     }
     section {
      background: blue
     }
```

```html
    
    <nav></nav>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
```

Nota: las alturas y colores de fondo están para permitir ver los elementos diferenciados entre si.

Comment: y una vez puesto quiero que el footer al poner en el section muchas cosas se vaya bajando con la altura del section.Y a mi lo que me pasa es que se queda quieto el footer y el section pasa por él.

Comment: @bsb yo creo que **no debes poner una altura al section**, este crecerá dinámicamente con los contenidos y el footer quedaría debajo. Puse alturas porque al no tener contenido las cajas no se verían.

Comment: voy a probarlo muchas gracias.

Comment: @bsg dar la gracias nunca esta de mas, pero stackoverflow tiene un mecanismo mucho mejor, puede leer el [tour], para entender mejor como funciona el sitio, y si esta respuesta ayudo o soluciono su problema proceder como corresponda. Saludos